# Configuring the IdentityModels navigation property with Guid for Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I get on creating Migration some Warnings like this one:

> The foreign key property 'AppUserClaim.UserId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'UserId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

It applies to all entities with AppUser navigation property. Other navigation properties has no warning.

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>, IChangeTrackerObject
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string ProfilePictureDataUrl { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public string ChangedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ChangedOn { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserToken> Tokens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

        public AppUser()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, IChangeTrackerObject
    {
        public string ChangedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ChangedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
private static void BuildIdentity(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "Users", schema);
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                // Each User can have many UserClaims
                entity.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many UserLogins
                entity.HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many UserTokens
                entity.HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
                entity.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserClaim>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserClaims", schema);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. In my `OnModelCreating` method, I had flipped the order in which I was applying migrations.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Basically, it seemed like if the call to the base method came after the call to apply the configurations from my code, then the configurations in the base method would override my configurations, which gave me a similar error to what you had. So what I'm assuming is happening is you're calling `BuildIdentity()` *after* you call `base.OnModelCreating()`. You may need to reverse that order, otherwise the relationships defined in the default identity DB may take precedence.